# how do I select test to run when using `bazel test ...`

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have a repo using bazel as build and test system. This repo has both python and golang. There are two types of tests, unit tests, and integration tests. I would like to run them in two separate test steps in our CI. I would like to automatically discover new tests in the repo when new tests are added. we are currently using `bazel test ...`. but this will not help me to split the unit test and integration test. Is there any rule or existing method to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Bazel doesn't really have a direct concept of unit vs integration testing, but it does have the concept of a test "size", or how "heavy" a test is. [This docs page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#test.size) gives an outline of the `size` attribute on test rules while the [Test encyclopedia](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html) gives a great overview.

When the tests are appropriately sized, it's then possible to use [`--test_size_filters`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--test_size_filters) flag to run the test for that size.

For example,

`bazel test ... --test_size_filters=small` for running unit tests

`bazel test ... --test_size_filters=large` for integration tests

You may want to add additional flags for unit tests vs integration tests, so adding a new config to [`.bazelrc`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#bazelrc-the-bazel-configuration-file) might be a good idea, then run via `bazel test ... --config=integration` for example.

Answer (score 3):

`--test_size_filters` is the best way, because it is a wide used solution. If you need another separation, then tags are way to go:

```py
py_test(
    name = "unit_test",
    tags = ["unit"],
)

py_test(
    name = "integration_test",
    tags = ["integration"],
)
```

And then

```sh
bazel test --test_tag_filters=unit //...
bazel test --test_tag_filters=integration //...
bazel test --test_tag_filters=-integration,-unit //... # each test which is not "unit" nor "integration"
```